# Is it possible to load secure content in InAppBrowser plugin of PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

I'm trying to use InAppBrowser plugin of PhoneGap to load secure content (https) in android emulator. Unfortunately, it always fails by showing "The webpage might be temporarily down" message. It loads the non secure version (http) correctly. Is there some privilege or setting I'm missing ?

Comment: Is the page secured by a valid certificate? Or is it somthing selfcreated and selfsigned?

Comment: Yes it is secured by a valid certificate (https://google.com). The non secure version of same site loads fine. While I'm providing 'https://google.com' as an example, my real goal is to do oauth by loading 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?'. Both links give the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read many times that android emulator can be slow but never attached much significance to it. Now I know it is so slow that a https call times out before it can be finished. Just think for a moment on how pathetically slow it must be for a https call to time out. It is also why http calls go through. They simply involve less processing. I finally figured all this out after installing intel emulator which is fast enough for the https call to complete.